# How to avoid code redundancy in ASP.NET MVC when using the dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I have two controllers and there is two function that they are doing the same code to create users according to many requirements. I want to avoid writing the same code for each controller. So what is the best practice to avoid the redundancy?

```
public class UsersController1 : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upsert()
    {
        //Code for Creation data in the database using _db dbcontext

        return View(UserAndAddressViewModel);
    }
}

public class UsersController2 : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upsert()
    {
        // Same Code for Creation data in the database using _db dbcontext

        return View(UserAndAddressViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would creating a `UserService` in a service-layer be an option?

Comment: Extract method, call from both

Comment: The concept you are trying to use is called [code reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_reuse). You need to create a generic module (functionality) that is accessible to both end points. There are many ways to do this like creating a "Service" type that is then called from either end point.

Comment: Why don't you create a base mvc controller and generic service?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a service to share the logic. By injecting the Service into your controller you can invoke the common logic.

```
class UserService {
    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;
    
    public UserService(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }
    
    public void Upsert(UserAndAddress userAndAddress)
    {
        // Place upsert logic
        
        // _db.Users.Add(userAndAddress);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Delete(UserAndAddress userAndAddress)
    {
        _db.Users.Remove(userAndAddress);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

First controller:

```
public class UsersController1 : Controller
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;

    public UsersController1(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upsert(UserAndAddress user)
    {
        //Code for Creation data in the database using _db dbcontext
        _userService.Upsert(user);
 
        return View(UserAndAddressViewModel);
    }
}
```

Controller 2

```
public class UsersController2 : Controller
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly ApplicationContext _db;

    public UsersController2(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upsert(UserAndAddress user)
    {
        // Same Code for Creation data in the database using _db dbcontext
        _userService.Upsert(user);

 
        return View(UserAndAddressViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: i like the idea of the service i will use that!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the [Repository Pattern](https://codewithshadman.com/repository-pattern-csharp/#:%7E:text=Repository%20pattern%20C%23%20is%20a%20way%20to%20implement,a%20more%20object-oriented%20view%20of%20the%20persistence%20layer.) if your code is going to have a lot of logic built into the CRUD aspects of your application.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about this being a controller in this regard. You can create your View method in a class that both controllers have access to and call it from there.

Comment: The logic has to be shared over two different controllers.